# Flutter. Scan QR Code, redirect to Screen

Tags: ios, flutter, camera, qr-code, mobile-development

I would like to create my own QR Code, Print it and whenever I want to scan it with my flutter app, it should redirect me to a screen of the app.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. There are several QR code reading packages on pub.dev and you can read the contents of your QR code and use it to direct your app to whichever view you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [qr_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/qr_flutter) package on pub.dev.

Answer (score 3):

import the qr_flutter package on pub.dev, this is the code to use below

```
import 'dart:developer';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:qr_code_scanner/qr_code_scanner.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyHome()));

class MyHome extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHome({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Flutter Demo Home Page')),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => QRViewExample(),
            ));
          },
          child: Text('qrView'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class QRViewExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _QRViewExampleState();
}

class _QRViewExampleState extends State<QRViewExample> {
  Barcode? result;
  QRViewController? controller;
  final GlobalKey qrKey = GlobalKey(debugLabel: 'QR');

  // In order to get hot reload to work we need to pause the camera if the platform
  // is android, or resume the camera if the platform is iOS.
  @override
  void reassemble() {
    super.reassemble();
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      controller!.pauseCamera();
    }
    controller!.resumeCamera();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(flex: 4, child: _buildQrView(context)),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: FittedBox(
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  if (result != null)
                    Text(
                        'Barcode Type: ${describeEnum(result!.format)}   Data: ${result!.code}')
                  else
                    Text('Scan a code'),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () async {
                              await controller?.toggleFlash();
                              setState(() {});
                            },
                            child: FutureBuilder(
                              future: controller?.getFlashStatus(),
                              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                return Text('Flash: ${snapshot.data}');
                              },
                            )),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () async {
                              await controller?.flipCamera();
                              setState(() {});
                            },
                            child: FutureBuilder(
                              future: controller?.getCameraInfo(),
                              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                if (snapshot.data != null) {
                                  return Text(
                                      'Camera facing ${describeEnum(snapshot.data!)}');
                                } else {
                                  return Text('loading');
                                }
                              },
                            )),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () async {
                            await controller?.pauseCamera();
                          },
                          child: Text('pause', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () async {
                            await controller?.resumeCamera();
                          },
                          child: Text('resume', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildQrView(BuildContext context) {
    // For this example we check how width or tall the device is and change the scanArea and overlay accordingly.
    var scanArea = (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < 400 ||
        MediaQuery.of(context).size.height < 400)
        ? 150.0
        : 300.0;
    // To ensure the Scanner view is properly sizes after rotation
    // we need to listen for Flutter SizeChanged notification and update controller
    return QRView(
      key: qrKey,
      onQRViewCreated: _onQRViewCreated,
      overlay: QrScannerOverlayShape(
          borderColor: Colors.red,
          borderRadius: 10,
          borderLength: 30,
          borderWidth: 10,
          cutOutSize: scanArea),
      onPermissionSet: (ctrl, p) => _onPermissionSet(context, ctrl, p),
    );
  }

  void _onQRViewCreated(QRViewController controller) {
    setState(() {
      this.controller = controller;
    });
    controller.scannedDataStream.listen((scanData) {
      setState(() {
        result = scanData;
      });
    });
  }

  void _onPermissionSet(BuildContext context, QRViewController ctrl, bool p) {
    log('${DateTime.now().toIso8601String()}_onPermissionSet $p');
    if (!p) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(content: Text('no Permission')),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```